# ormlite DataType.ENUM_STRING gives me "is not valid for data persister"

Tags: android, ormlite

Hello i am using ORMLite 4.33.

I have an entity class that gives me an error when trying to destroyTable:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6715): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class
     java.lang.String for field FieldType:name=udm,class=Prodotti is not valid
     for data persister com.j256.ormlite.field.types.EnumStringType@40a3a2e0
```

here is the class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Prodotti")
public class Prodotti extends BaseDaoEnabled{
    ....
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_STRING,
         columnDefinition="VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL")
    //also tried @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_STRING)
    private String udm;
    ...
 }
```

I runned DatabaseConfigUtil to update the ormlite_config.txt, right now i'm thinking the only solution is to change the type of the field to String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support database SQL enum columns which are only supported by a couple of database types.  The `ENUM_STRING` is supposed to persist an enum type.  Something like:

```
 @DatabaseField
 private OurEnum udm;
 ...

 public enum OurEnum {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;
 }
```

By default, ORMLite will then persist the enum as it's string value (RED, GREEN, BLUE) in a `VARCHAR` SQL field.  If you have a `String` field then you should just let it be persisted as a `STRING` type.  You can also use the `DataType.ENUM_INTEGER` if you want to store its value instead but that is not recommended for backwards compatibility reasons.

If you edit your questions to better explain what you are trying to accomplish, I can edit my answer to provide more information.

Comment: so with this code OurEnum becomes varchar not enum in the database?

Comment: As the answer states, the `OurEnum` field will get persisted in the database as a `VARCHAR` in the database.  ORMLite does not support database enums which is only supported by a couple of database types.